# How to create a temporary table in package PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I created a package and I want to create a temporary table inside stored procedure in this package body. But I can not do this because of giving an error message saying insufficient privileges. I can create tables but inside stored procedure, I can not do. Please anyone can help me to create a temporary table inside stored procedure?

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_MY_TESTING AS

PROCEDURE PRC_MY_TESTING_DATA(DATE DATE, ID NUMBER)
IS

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE all_muster_ids                                                         
    ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS AS                                                                                  
   SELECT *
      FROM MY_TABLE';                                                                                              
COMMIT;                                                                                         
EXCEPTION                                                                                        
WHEN OTHERS THEN                                                                                                      
ROLLBACK;                                                                                   

END PRC_MY_TESTING_DATA;                                                                                  
END PKG_MY_TESTING;
```

Comment: You shouldn't normally create database objects on the fly. If you are planning to create and then drop the temporary table, have you looked at PL/SQL collections instead? (Also, sounds like your create table privilege is granted via a role rather than directly to your user; and you can't rollback DDL, it commits implicitly; and catching `when others` is a dangerous habit to get into).

Comment: Yes. I checked BULK Collect. But I do not need to iterate data for my usage. I just want to use data with some condition. After that, I do not need those data.

Comment: In another query? Why not just join to `my_table` then, what's the point of the temporary table? Your problem is with how privileges are assigned to you, but fixing your methodology is probably better than getting your privileges changed.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33774836/266304).

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Alex - this is not the right way to solve the problem. Or if you really don't think you can use a join please edit your question to explain your extraordinary circumstances.

Comment: My requirement is to delete some data in several tables.What I tried is to keep those data in a temporary table to use when deleting. Then I do not need to requery the data. If I use join, I have to use this join query every deletion. Is there any other way to keep my data where I can load data once and delete data after finish the work?